# How to deploy python program on Ec2 or AWS lamda? Or any server

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, amazon-ec2, twitter

I have a program, that tweets content that I scraped from a website. So I use selenium and a bunch of python libraries. I have found a lot of YouTube videos about selenium grid, aws lambda, etc and I have also deployed a twitter before on ec2.but I find it hard to understand as this time I have selenium. I need the web driver and chrome browser setup.

My program has a bot.py, Image folder where images are saved and deleted and a func.py where functions are saved.

Code is ready but needs deployment, I need a clarity and use case on how to do it. My research after watching and reading content on internet is stressing me out. I’m a newbie, FYI.

Comment: What is your question? If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: Okay. I’ll ask there. Btw, if you can help, I wanted to know the steps to deploy it on a server.

Comment: It's quite difficult to answer such an open-ended question. If your Python program is written for the command-line, then converting it to a web application will require a framework like Flask. If, on the other hand, you already have it working as a web app on your own computer, then you could deploy it to an EC2 instance (which is just another computer). AWS Lambda functions, however, normally operate in response to something and can't be used as a typical web server.

Comment: Ec2 suits my program I feel. I think I can take it away from here and from your advice. If it requires help, I’ll update add my code and edit the complete question here. Thanks again.